# XLSX Report should be shown in single sheet for Odoo10

Tags: report, odoo, xlsx, odoo-10

I generate xlsx report for a list of customers and my report generated according to individual customer wise means for 4 customers 4 sheets generated. But, I want a single sheet for multiple customers list.

my code and screenshots are here:

```py
from odoo.addons.report_xlsx.report.report_xlsx import ReportXlsx

class PartnerXlsx(ReportXlsx):
    def generate_xlsx_report(self, workbook, data, partners):
        for obj in partners:
            report_name = obj.name
            print("REPRTTTTTTT", report_name, report_name[:31])
            # One sheet by partner
            sheet = workbook.add_worksheet(report_name[:31])
            bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
            sheet.write(0, 0, obj.name, bold)
            sheet.write(0, 1, obj.email, bold)
            sheet.write(0, 2, obj.telephone, bold)
PartnerXlsx('report.res.partner.xlsx', 'res.partner')
```

**Now: 5 sheets generated for 5 customers**
[image]

**Requirement: One sheet for all user**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:

```py
from odoo.addons.report_xlsx.report.report_xlsx import ReportXlsx

class PartnerXlsx(ReportXlsx):
   def generate_xlsx_report(self, workbook, data, partners):
       sheet = workbook.add_worksheet(report_name[:31])
       counter = 0
       for obj in partners:
          report_name = obj.name
           print("REPRTTTTTTT", report_name, report_name[:31])
          # One sheet by partner

            bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
            sheet.write(counter, 0, obj.name, bold)
            sheet.write(counter, 1, obj.email, bold)
            sheet.write(counter, 2, obj.telephone, bold)
            counter = counter + 1
PartnerXlsx('report.res.partner.xlsx', 'res.partner')
```